# How can I add an AJAX callback to a checkbox?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am using taxonomy manager module I want to add ajax callback to checkbox tree view for checkbox is checked condition but it is not working can some one please suggest me. I have modified the code like this

```php
$form[$term->tid]['checkbox'] = array(
      '#type' => ($multiple) ? 'checkbox' : 'radio',
      '#title' => $term->name, // Escaping is done in theme wrappers.
      '#value' => $value,
      '#return_value' => $term->tid,
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
      '#required' => FALSE,
      '#theme_wrappers' => ($multiple) ? array('taxonomy_manager_tree_checkbox') : array('taxonomy_manager_tree_radio'),
      '#highlight' => in_array($term->tid, $terms_to_highlight) ? TRUE : FALSE,
    );
```

This is the taxonomy manager module theme function.

```php
function theme_taxonomy_manager_tree_checkbox($variables) {
  global $user;
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';
  $element['#attributes']['ajax']['event'] = 'change';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element['#checked'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox'));
  $output = '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  /* custom alter function */
  if(user_is_logged_in()){
    if(!user_access('administer taxonomy')){
      $cdms_taxonomy_id = taxonomy_term_load($element['#return_value']); 
      // echo "IF"; exit;     
    }else{
      $cdms_taxonomy_id = taxonomy_term_load($element['#return_value']);
      // echo "Else"; exit;      
    }
  }
  // echo '<pre>';print_r($variables);  echo"Term load"; print_r($cdms_taxonomy_id);  exit;
  $data = [
    'title' =>  $element['#title'],
    'tid' => @$cdms_taxonomy_id->field_cdms_txy_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][value],
    'count' => '',
  ];
  // Calling all modules implementing hook_my_data_alter():
  drupal_alter('my_data', $data);
  
  if (!in_array("Client User", array_values($user->roles))) {
  $title = $element['#title'] ."(".$data['count'].")";
}else{
   $title = $element['#title'];
}
  if (in_array("Client User", array_values($user->roles))) {
    $title = check_plain($title);
  }else{
    if (isset($element['#link'])) {
        $attr = array();
        $attr["class"][] = "term-data-link";
        $attr["class"][] = "term-data-link-id-" . $element['#return_value'];
        if (isset($element['#extra_info'])) {
          $attr["title"] = $element['#extra_info'];
        }
        $title = l($title, $element['#link'], array('attributes' => $attr));
      }
      else {
        $title = check_plain($title);
      }
  }
  
  $element['#children'] = '<label class="option">' . $output . ' ' . $title . '</label>';
  $element['#title_display'] = 'none';
  return theme('form_element', array('element' => $element));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback` function is not defined in the above code.

Also please update more info about what you are trying to do.

```
$form[$term->tid] = array(... 'ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback' ...); //ajax callback
$form['tree']; //new field.
```

after the above function call you can get new `built_info` of `$form_state` as its rebuilt. So you can alter output of the field.

```
function ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback($form, $form_state) {
  dsm($form_state);
  return $form['tree']; // this is a new field.
}
```

I will update my answer if more information is provided.